# GMAIL shows message clipped when using file_get_contents

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have switched to using an HTML template when sending email using PHPmailer. After doing so I receive a message within GMAIL stating `[Message clipped] View entire message`

In troubleshooting I have tried deleting the contents of the HTML template file so that it is blank, but still receive the clipped message. However, if I copy the HTML template code directly in to `$mail->MsgHTML('');` and don't use `file_get_contents` I do not receive that the message was clipped. This leads me to believe something within the `file_get_contents` is causing the issue?

I should add that there isn't anything actually being clipped from the email when the message is displayed.

```
$message = file_get_contents('path_to_HTML_template'); 
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->send();
```

Comment: confirm its gmail or file_get contents. just try to print the contents before sending . https://mailchimp.com/help/gmail-is-clipping-my-email/

Comment: You don't need to convert entities, just be sure your content is in valid UTF-8. So do you still have an issue or not?

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem for me too - Can you cut out your updates and make them an answer and mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

Apparently I needed to convert the template to HTML-ENTITIES before sending:

```
$message = mb_convert_encoding($message, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
```

UPDATE 2

And the reason I was having to use `mb_convert_encoding` was due to a BOM (byte order mark) in my HTML template file. After removing this I no longer have to convert the template.